# How to globally change the command timeout using ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a reporting-based website using `ServiceStack` and `OrmLite`, using a SQL Server back-end.  Due to the duration of some of the reports, I'd like to either globally, or selectively (via `Service`-derived class or some attribute) make queries that run reports have a longer `CommandTimeout`.  I'd like to keep using the existing code to query data for the reports (`Db.Select`, `Db.SqlList` calls), so I won't have to write boiler-plate code in each reporting class & method.

I've tried using the `AlwaysUseCommand`, but that requires declaring a single command that has an open connection. I don't see how I can do that without opening the connection in my `AppHost.Configure` method and never closing it.  It'd be nicer if it were a function pointer, but alas.

I've also looked at overriding the `Db` property of `Service`, but that just returns an open `IDbConnection` without letting me override command created.

It seems like my last option is to create a custom `DbConnection` class, like the MiniProfiler's [ProfiledDbConnection](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/MiniProfiler/Data/ProfiledDbConnection.cs), but I'd have to implement a dozen abstract methods.  It seems like overkill in order to set one property on a DbCommand.

So, in `ServiceStack.OrmLite`, how do I globally modify the `CommandTimeout` of `DbCommand`s that are created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `CommandTimeout` globally with:

```
OrmLiteConfig.CommandTimeout = NewTimeoutInSeconds;
```

#### Scoped Timeout

You can also specify a Timeout for a particular db connection with:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.SetCommandTimeout(NewTimeoutInSeconds);
}
```

Comment: * face-palm *  Happy Friday.

Comment: One additional question though - what if we have multiple DB connections, or only want to apply the override in specific situations?  Basically - is there something between static global and individual command?

Comment: @jklemmack Updated answer with specifying command timeout for single db conneciton.

Comment: Quote: "Be very careful using db.SetCommandTimeout in a threaded application as in our case it seemed to cause running commands to instantly timeout on other connections on other threads. Setting the Global one fixed the issue. Just took us 3 days to work out why doing 1 thread worked and multiple timed out after 30 seconds when we set timeout to unlimited by setting 0. Use global setting if possible to avoid lots of pain." - http://www.itdaan.com/faq/2014/09/18/101151674.html